# Connect to an existing session in Powershell by its id

Tags: powershell

For a really specific use, i need to connect to an existing session which have a opened desktop (with gui). To maintain the gui, we opened the session with rdp and already use a powershell script which transform the rdp session into a console session (without exiting gui since the session technicaly stay open).
Before, I used psexec with the -i parameter set (I got the session's Id by the username) but now, I'm trying to do the same with pure powershell.
Any thought?

Comment: It sounds to me like you'd want to look into disconnected sessions. However, I don't think you can connect to a GUI session that way ever as a matter of system security. It has to be created as a remote session in the first place (even created locally) to be able to disconnect from it. See `Get-Help about_Disconnected_Sessions`.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a native PS cmdlet to do this kind of thing

Comment: Actually, creating a session with gui is'nt the problem: i create it with rdp and I let it opened with a powershell workaround (I use tscon to convert the rdp session into consolle session. This way, i technically am disconnected from the rdp but the session and the gui remains active.
The problem is after that: when I try to reconnect myself to the session. With psexec, i can do it with the session Id but I dont' know how to do that with powershell...